# How to outer join multiple tables to retrieve uncommon records

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to do an outer join in MySQL to identify records not common to 3 tables. Here's my current effort http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02b92/30

I'm trying to retrieve the records not common to all three tables: 2,C,c (tbl2) 6,E,c (tbl3). Instead, I'm getting back the one common record: 1,A,c.

Thanks

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 B
ON(
  A.a = B.a 
  AND A.b = B.b
  AND A.c = B.c
)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl3 C
ON(
  B.a = C.a 
  AND B.b = C.b
  AND B.c = C.c
)
WHERE A.a is not null;
```

Comment: I think this question should stay here, not migrated to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not dead set upon using `OUTER JOIN` a way to get the expected result is

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   (SELECT 'tbl1' name, a, b, c
        FROM   tbl1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'tbl2' name, a, b, c
        FROM   tbl2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'tbl3' name, a, b, c
        FROM   tbl2) d
GROUP BY a, b, c
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) < 3
```

otherwise you need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` a type of join not supported by MySQL, but it can be emulated with a composition like ([Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql))

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl1
RIGHT JOIN tbl2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: This first query works perfectly! However, I wasn't able to get the second one to work as I needed it. Awarded you the answer.

Comment: The second one is a template for the `FULL OUTER JOIN` not the full query, that one will be similar to the query of JChao

Answer (score 0):

I know it is ugly but I believe it works.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 
left OUTER JOIN tbl2 
ON(
  tbl1.a = tbl2.a 
  AND tbl1.b = tbl2.b
  AND tbl1.c = tbl2.c
)
left OUTER JOIN tbl3
ON(
  tbl2.a = tbl3.a 
  AND tbl2.b = tbl3.b
  AND tbl2.c = tbl3.c
)
WHERE tbl1.a is null or tbl2.a is null or tbl3.a is null
union
select *
from tbl1
right OUTER JOIN tbl2 
ON(
  tbl1.a = tbl2.a 
  AND tbl1.b = tbl2.b
  AND tbl1.c = tbl2.c
)
right OUTER JOIN tbl3
ON(
  tbl2.a = tbl3.a 
  AND tbl2.b = tbl3.b
  AND tbl2.c = tbl3.c
)
WHERE tbl1.a is null or tbl2.a is null or tbl3.a is null
union
select * from tbl1
right outer join tbl2
ON(
  tbl1.a = tbl2.a 
  AND tbl1.b = tbl2.b
  AND tbl1.c = tbl2.c
)
left OUTER JOIN tbl3
ON(
  tbl2.a = tbl3.a 
  AND tbl2.b = tbl3.b
  AND tbl2.c = tbl3.c
)
WHERE tbl1.a is null or tbl2.a is null or tbl3.a is null
```